# how do i set the button to play Interstitial ad first instead it sync with other action

Tags: flutter, dart

how do i set the button on the first press, it shown the ad, after closing the ad its still back to the previous menu and the second tap, it load other action.

thanks in advance.

```
  void showPopUpButton(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => Dialog(
        backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        child: IconButton(
          icon: Image.asset('lib/images/last.png'),
          iconSize: 260,
          onPressed: () async {
            _showInterstitialAd();
            setState(() {});
            initRandomImage();
            Navigator.pop(context);

            final player = AudioPlayer();
            await player.play(AssetSource('Sound1.wav'),
                volume: 1.0);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try including your IconButton inside a StatefulWidget and inside the StatefulWidget, keep the record of whether the ad has been already displayed or not, before navigating to the actual action as below:
Your function:

```
void showPopUpButton(BuildContext context) {
  showDialog(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Dialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
      child: DialogButtonWidget(),
    ),
  );
}
```

The DialogButtonWidget:

```
class DialogButtonWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DialogButtonWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DialogButtonWidget> createState() => _DialogButtonWidgetState();
}

class _DialogButtonWidgetState extends State<DialogButtonWidget> {
  bool _interstitialAdDisplayed = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return IconButton(
      icon: Image.asset('lib/images/last.png'),
      iconSize: 260,
      onPressed: () async {
        if (!_interstitialAdDisplayed) {
          _showInterstitialAd();
          setState(() {
            _interstitialAdDisplayed = true;
          });
        } else {
          initRandomImage();
          Navigator.pop(context);
          final player = AudioPlayer();
          await player.play(AssetSource('Sound1.wav'), volume: 1.0);
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks , from the class _dialogbuttonwidgetstate extends all the with the widget build ?Because i am getting red curly on that class.

Comment: I didn't get you. Please explain clearly

Comment: so the class _DialogButtonWidgetState extends State<DialogButtonWidget> { bool _interstitialAdDisplayed = false; , is a new class , i cant place it inside or out a class

Comment: If that is the case, define the bool field (bool _interstitialAdDisplayed = false;) inside the class that's calling the function showPopUpButton, and change the logic for onPressed of the OutlineButton with the one I have written.